# Javascript Cross Domain Authentication

Tags: php, javascript

I have a JavaScript which can be called externally using `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/myscript.js"></script>` the script is created dynamically using php but I need to know where the script is being called from (which domain) the only way i can think off is using `$ SERVER["HTTP REFERER"]` but not all browsers support this and it is insecure as it can be changed.

Dose anyone know a better way I could do it?

Comment: "and it is insecure as it can be changed." - because this is a javascript request, you are relying on the user to be truthful. They can change anything. They could change the host it is loaded from as well.

Comment: Why do you use JavaScript for this? Do you want to provide an actual session?

Answer (score 0):

First of all anything the browser provides cannot be trusted, this includes the [HTTP Referer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer).

However I don't agree with this being insecure, what exactly are you doing with this information?  All the server can do is trust what the browser supplies it, so if you are attempting to restrict this javascript you are going to have to authenticate the user first (so you can plant a cookie).

So what exactly are your intentions?

Comment: The JavaScript allows websites connect to my DB and search it but i need to know which domain the script is being called from as i limit the number of searches per day, i did implement a license key however unscrupulous webmasters have been registering multiple accounts, the only way i can stop this is by getting the refering domain and registering the key against it.

Comment: So surely the javascript can be copied by said webmasters?  You need to implement security **server-side** where you would ask for a key / password that you provided.  Look at any API out there, this is how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my idea.

Use a PHP file to render the JS file contents and it will only serve the javascript when session id matches. Hide your real js file too